# Spark 2.0 Possible Bug on DataFrame Initialization

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There is possible bug that is produced by the following code :

```
_struct = [
  types.StructField('string_field', types.StringType(), True),
  types.StructField('long_field', types.LongType(), True),
  types.StructField('double_field', types.DoubleType(), True)
]
_rdd = sc.parallelize([Row(string_field='1', long_field=1, double_field=1.1)])
_schema = types.StructType(_struct)
_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(_rdd, schema=_schema)
_df.take(1)
```

The expected output is an RDD with 1 row should be created.

But with the current behavior I receive the following error:

```
DoubleType can not accept object '1' in type <type 'str'>
```

**PS:** I'm using spark 2.0 compile on Scala 2.10

**Edit**

Thanks to the answerer's suggestion, I can properly understand this now. To simplify, make sure that the struct is sorted. The following code explains this:

```
# This doesn't work:
_struct = [
  SparkTypes.StructField('string_field', SparkTypes.StringType(), True),
  SparkTypes.StructField('long_field', SparkTypes.LongType(), True),
  SparkTypes.StructField('double_field', SparkTypes.DoubleType(), True)
]
_rdd = sc.parallelize([Row(string_field='1', long_field=1, double_field=1.1)])

# But this will work, since schema is sorted:
_struct = sorted([
  SparkTypes.StructField('string_field', SparkTypes.StringType(), True),
  SparkTypes.StructField('long_field', SparkTypes.LongType(), True),
  SparkTypes.StructField('double_field', SparkTypes.DoubleType(), True)
], key=lambda x: x.name)
params = {'string_field':'1', 'long_field':1, 'double_field':1.1}
_rdd = sc.parallelize([Row(**params)])


_schema = SparkTypes.StructType(_struct)

_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(_rdd, schema=_schema)
_df.take(1)

_schema = SparkTypes.StructType(_struct)

_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(_rdd, schema=_schema)
_df.take(1)
```

Comment: did you mean scala 2.10 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a change of behavior between 1.x and 2.x but I doubt it is a bug. In particular when you create `Row` object with `kwargs` (named arguments) [the fields are sorted by names](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/274f3b9ec86e4109c7678eef60f990d41dc3899f/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L1375-L1376). Let's illustrate that with a simple example:

```py
Row(string_field='1', long_field=1, double_field=1.1)
## Row(double_field=1.1, long_field=1, string_field='1'
```

As you can see order of fields change and is no longer reflected in the schema.

Prior to 2.0.0 Spark verifies types [only if `data` argument for `createDataFrame` is a local data structure](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/python/pyspark/sql/context.py#L348-L350). So following code:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    data=[Row(string_field='1', long_field=1, double_field=1.1)], 
    schema=_schema
)
```

would fail in 1.6 as well

Spark 2.0.0 introduced [verification for `RDDs`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/274f3b9ec86e4109c7678eef60f990d41dc3899f/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L525) and provides consistent behavior between local and distributed inputs.